# SVG: How to make a stroke of an object overlap an object rendered after it

Tags: svg, path, overlap, stroke

I have a SVG-image map with many polygons, which are directly bordering and all have a white stroke. On hovering, that stroke should turn darkgrey and become wider. Easy CSS.

But my problem: As objects in SVG are rendered after one another, the wider stroke will not overlap the other object, but underlap it, which looks super ugly. Is there a way to make it overlap instead?

Thanks in advance,
snow

Comment: Draw a second set of shapes with fill: none and the thicker stroke and display: none. The hover turns off the display: none on the second copy of the shape; or move the shape earlier in the document; or if the polygons are all the same type - draw the hover stroke once and move it to the appropriate place using transforms.

Comment: I gave the second set of shapes the class st3

`.st3{fill:none;display:none;stroke:darkgrey;stroke-width:1;}
 .st3:hover{fill:none;stroke:darkgrey;stroke-width:1;}`

That doesn't seem to work, though,

Comment: Did you draw all the overlay shapes after first drawing all the initial shapes? That should work. Maybe post a minimum verifiable test case - so people can see the actual code